# "just starting" vs "starting"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I can't get the difference between these ones in the following context. In PEU, Swan is talking about the differences between uses of the present progressive and the **going to** structure in sentences about the future. What he says is

> We often use the present progressive with verbs of movement, to talk about
>   actions which are *just starting*.

and

> Another use of the **going to** structure is to predict the future on the
>   basis of present evidence - to say that a future action or event is on
>   the way, or *starting to happen*

He also provides the following examples:

> Look at the sky. It's **gonna** rain.

and

> **Are** you **coming** to the pub?

Could you explain the difference between the phrase using examples?

Comment: tell me the entry number in PEU

Comment: @MaulikV 220/2 Second edition.

Comment: Ah...I got the 3rd edition...not the same entry number it seems. Will search and get back... :)

Comment: Can you rephrase and ask this in a clearer way? What's confusing you? *going to* used for future?

Comment: @MaulikV I don't feell the difference between _an action is starting to happen_ and _an action which is just starting_. There definitely is the difference, because in the first case we should use _going to_ structure, but in the second _the present progressive_.

Comment: *Just starting* or *starting* -in both the instances, *going to* is fine! Talking about the heading of the question. *It's going to be the best match* - I can tell that even at the last minute. I can say the same thing an hour back! Maybe, I need to reread the question! :(

Comment: I have exactly the same question. Have you solved this problem? Ifyou have, would you post your answer?

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking for the difference between *starting* and *just starting*, that is, what does the word "just" add to the meaning, there's a fine shade of difference.

If it's *just starting to rain*, you've felt the first few raindrops of a rain shower that will grow gradually in its intensity.  If it's a "cloudburst", a sudden downpour which comes all at once, we wouldn't say "it's just starting to rain".

If the movie is "just starting", it's at the opening scene.

> Have you played guitar long?
>   -- No, I'm just starting. I know a few basic chords.

So "just" refers to the earliest moments of the beginning.  "The beginning of the beginning."

P.S. If you want to know what he means by predicting the (imminent) future on the basis of present evidence:

**The vase is going to fall over!**  (maybe someone knocked into the table and the vase has started to wobble)

**Don't inflate the tire any higher! It's going to burst!**  (maybe you can see a bubble forming)

But there is no marked difference between the imminent future, the close future, or the distant future.

**The almanac predicts that this summer is going to be a hot one.**

**My aunt is going to take a trip to China some day.**